# Numpy shuffle array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-random

I'm using Numpy to shuffle an array with about 1 million entries. The resulting array doesn't seem to be in random order at all, I can see sequences.

Eg if the original is:

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

then I see sequences like this in the result:

```
[6,7,8,5,10,1,2,3,4]
```

Is this normal and is there a better way to shuffle an array in Numpy?

---

EDIT:

Code:
    np.random.shuffle(ar)

Output sequences my eyes spot:

510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
640
638
608
608
608
650
650
650
650
650
650
650
0
0
0
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
650
650
568
568
568
568
568
1280
568
568
568
568
568
568
568
608
608
608
608
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
640
640
600
600
600
600
0
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
640
640
660
650
650
0
0
608
608
608
608
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
650
650
650
650
650
650
650
568
608
568
568
568
568
568
568
568
608
608
608
608
608
608
608
608
608
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
640
640
600
600
600
600
600
640
0
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
510
640
660
608
608
608
608
640
650
650
650
650
0
0
0
0
0
640
608
608
608
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
640
650

---

EDIT 2: test with input:

`200000 x 1
400000 x 2
250000 x 3
5000 x 4
700000 x 5
2000000 x 6
175000 x 7
225000 x 8
700000 x 9
350000 x 10
75000 x 11
5000000 x 12
2000000 x 13
450000 x 14
50000 x 15
350000 x 16
900000 x 17
2500000 x 18
2000000 x 19
50000 x 20`

`np.random.shuffle(a)`

First 100 results:

17, 
6, 
18, 
12, 
19, 
14, 
13, 
13, 
19, 
18, 
12, 
12, 
14, 
12, 
13, 
19, 
17, 
8, 
19, 
3, 
6, 
18, 
6, 
9, 
12, 
12, 
3, 
16, 
3, 
12, 
14, 
9, 
6, 
5, 
18, 
12, 
19, 
1, 
5, 
13, 
19, 
5, 
6, 
5, 
18, 
12, 
13, 
7, 
12, 
12, 
2, 
18, 
11, 
12, 
13, 
19, 
6, 
18, 
19, 
13, 
7, 
12, 
6, 
9, 
12, 
12, 
18, 
2, 
20, 
6, 
6, 
19, 
19, 
13, 
19, 
12, 
12, 
12, 
12, 
19, 
13, 
18, 
19, 
6, 
13, 
6, 
18, 
6, 
12, 
9, 
13, 
12, 
17, 
1, 
12, 
17, 
19, 
13, 
13, 
18,

Comment: `[6,7,8,5,10,1,2,3,4]` is as likely as any other ordering... can you show us *how* you're shuffling the array.

Comment: Genuinely random things tend to look patterned because human brains are very good at spotting patterns, and having no patterns at all is itself a pattern and quite an unusual one. So the fact that you see some patterns might be perfectly OK.

Or it might not. A single example of a 10-element sequence doesn't tell us much.

Could you show us (1) the relevant code and/or (2) a larger sample of the output and some indication of what about it looks non-random to you?

Comment: I added the code and the sample to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Is your array one-dimensional or multidimensional?

Comment: 1D 1D 1D 1D 1D 1D (sorry SO doesn't allow 2 character comments)

Comment: (and the values are defined as UINT32)

Comment: A MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.  Without seeing the input, I don't see how anyone can decide if the output that you show is somehow not random.

Comment: Whatever the input, with only ~ 1 million numbers going in nothing in the output should look much like the output quoted by *tdma*. But, *tdma*, it's not very clear: what does "output sequences" mean? E.g., did you run the thing once and find each of those consecutive runs (e.g., 23 consecutive instances of 510) in the same output? Or are different bits from different runs? Or what? What can you tell us about the distribution of values in the input?

Comment: Were the contents of `ar` created by reading in data from some external source, or "from scratch" by your code? Can you show us that code, or tell us more about the data? What are you doing to look at the output? (If you are writing it out in some clever way and have a bug there, that could perhaps produce strange results.)

Comment: Hi Gareth. Those values come from input sources, so in the input array, they are going to be mostly sorted. Eg 1 million x 510, followed by 100k times 640, followed by 4 million values 1280, etc. (They are screen resolutions, but that's not relevant for the question.) I said 1 million but I've done it with up to 25 million values. Probably repititions would be a better term than sequences. Then I do np.random.shuffle, and I get for instance the 23 consecutive values of 510, which is nothing compared to 1 million consecutive values, but still, I was looking for a better mix 'n shake...

Comment: So are all those repeated sequences from a single one of your hopefully-shuffled outputs? Or is each of them the worst thing you see in one single run? Here's a quick back-of-envelope calculation. Suppose you have a million values and half of them are 1234; then on average the longest block of consecutive 1234s in the output will be of length about 20. (That's the base-2 log of a million.) On the other hand, if only 1/4 of the values are 1234 then you need the base-4 log instead and the longest block will usually be ~ 10 long.

Comment: So: If your arrays are typically of size about 25 million, and if a single value typically makes up half of each array, then a longest block of length 24 or thereabouts is not a big surprise. But if your arrays are typically of size about 1 million, and no single value typically makes up more than 1/4 of it, a block of length 20 would be very surprising (if `np.random.shuffle` is doing its job right). Could you be more explicit about what those "output sequences" actually represent?

Comment: I'll try to write a test setup over the weekend to test np.random.shuffle to exclude possible problems with my code.

Comment: If you can tell us more about how much actual "blockiness" you're seeing in the output -- being more specific about what those "output sequences" represent -- then we can figure out whether "The Doctor"'s answer -- i.e., that this is just what you should expect -- is correct or not. If it is, no need for you to investigate further. If not, perhaps we can get a better idea of *what* further investigation is most useful.

Comment: First I would need to learn myself exactly how scattered the input data is, cause as you say, there is a difference between 1 and 25 million, hence the tests.

Comment: I just added a test to the original question. Here I add about 18 million values to an array spread over 20 values with different occurrances, but sorted. The output seems to be sufficiently shuffled. So I think @GarethMcCaughan is right and that my input values are too repetitive, quoting his answer: "If your arrays are typically of size about 25 million, and if a single value typically makes up half of each array, then a longest block of length 24 or thereabouts is not a big surprise."

Answer (score 0):

You're bound to see sequences (if you're really lucky even everything in order). I assume you're doing `np.random.shuffle(ar)`. This will do a [pseudo random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) reordering of the elements. For all practical purposes this is the randomness you're looking for.

Try running:

```
for _ in range(1000):
   np.random.shuffle(ar)
   print(ar)
```

looking at the results you'll find some sequences and possibly even repeats but each one is in-fact a random re-ordering of your array.

Comment: It's true that "you're bound to see sequences". But, at least on the face of it, the output reported by *tdma* appears to have much longer runs of consecutive identical numbers than we should expect. (Of course in principle anything can happen, but the probability of getting such results should be extremely low.) So most likely there is something wrong either with what *tdma* is doing, or with how s/he is reporting the results, or with `np.random.shuffle`.

Comment: On further discussion in comments (see above) it looks as if maybe the "output sequences" reported by *tdma* are (1) not all from the same run, (2) from input data with an awful lot of repeated values, and (3) from larger data files than *tdma* originally suggested. In which case, I agree  with your assessment of the situation.

Comment: The downvote your answer got was from me, when I had a completely different understanding of tdma's reported output. Unfortunately, since that was > 4 hours ago, I can't undo it unless your answer is edited. You might e.g. want to insert a space after "pseudo random" :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan edited. You can remove the downvote now ;)